# Fitting a convolution of a fermi function with a Gaussian function to real data with python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting, convolution

I am dealing with Photoemission data recently and want to estimate the instrumental resolution by fitting a convolution of a fermi function with a gaussian to real data. For now i neglect that i also have to incorporate a background.
I tried to work a soultion based on what i found in [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368151/fitting-an-exponential-decay-using-a-convolution-integral-python)

Unfortunately i am now stuck and would kindly ask you for help. I provide a small example were i simullated data which ( judged by eye) is actually a good representation of real data expet that a background is missing:

```
import array as ar
import math
from math import e, sqrt, pi
import pylab as plt
from numpy import array, linspace, arange, zeros, ceil, amax, amin, argmax, argmin, abs
from numpy import polyfit, polyval, seterr, trunc, mean
from numpy.linalg import norm
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import scipy.optimize
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

kb = 8.6173e-5 # Boltzmann k in eV/K


def f(e,scale,T=300,muf=0):
    return scale*(1.0 / (np.exp((-e - muf)/(kb*T)) + 1)) # -e due to binding energy scale

def gaussian(x, mu, sig,scale):
    return scale*(np.exp(-np.power(-x - mu, 2.) / (2 * np.power(sig, 2.))))  # -x due to binding energy scale




Points=10000 # If i change the points the "modelt data" doesn not look good anymore?
espan = np.linspace(-10, 10, Points)


# simulate the fermi edge data such that is close to the read real data
# note that it actually is a convoluiton of a fermi and a gaussian function.
Sim_data = np.random.normal((8.07+np.convolve(f(espan,scale=1.05), gaussian(espan, mu=0, sig=0.3,scale=1.05),mode="same")),10)

# min max norm not ( not used for now )
# Sim_data_norm = ((Sim_data - Sim_data.min()) / (Sim_data.max() - Sim_data.min()))


# convolution
# I know the actual data was meassured at T=300K so i preset this value in the fermi function
# The position of the fermi function and the gaussian should be 0 so mu and muf are set to 0
# i guess x_values would have to be replaced for the x axis of my real data later?
def Gaus_fermi_convolution(size,sigC,scaleC,xC=espan):
    return size* np.convolve(gaussian(x=xC,sig=sigC,scale=scaleC,mu=0), f(e=espan,scale=scaleC,T=300,muf=0), mode="same") 

# try to fit
lowerBounds = [0.0, 0.0,0.0] # A, B, C ,D lower bounds
upperBounds = [440.0, 0.6,440.0] # A, B, C, D upper bounds

popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(Gaus_fermi_convolution, espan, Sim_data,bounds=[lowerBounds, upperBounds])
Opt_size,Opt_sigC,Opt_scaleC = popt

# Print out the coefficients determined by the optimization
print(Opt_size,Opt_sigC,Opt_scaleC)

# Plotting 
plt.plot(espan,Sim_data)
#The result is clearly wrong
plt.plot(espan,Gaus_fermi_convolution(size=Opt_size,sigC=Opt_sigC,scaleC=Opt_scaleC,xC=espan))

plt.xlim([2, -2])
plt.xlabel( r'$Binding \: Energy  \: [eV]$')
plt.ylabel(r'$Intensity\: [arb. u.] $')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Two questions. 1) I see that the fitted data range and plotted data range are not the same, as the  plot X axis limits are from -2 to 2. Is [-2, 2] also the desired fitting range? 2) The scipy default initial parameter values are all 1.0 and one of your bounds is from 0.0 to 0.6, is this intentional?

Comment: If i change the definition `espan = np.linspace(-10, 10, Points)` only to `espan = np.linspace(-2, 2, Points)` somehow the colvolution doe not yield in a result that represents the data well i want to actually fit. I am only interested in a fit for the Region from -2 to 2 for my actual data. If i understand it correctly the parameter i set a bound of 0.6 is the sigC parameter of the gaussian which is intentional.